# jQuery date picker Day counter

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

How do I get this http://jsfiddle.net/L2et3/11/ to output the difference in days between the "from" and "to" date pickers in the "number of days" box when the "to" date is entered? I don't want the alert box triggered from the button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to visit the documentation page of the jQuery UI controls.http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: I did and the answer was not there

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to give the input element an id like id="numDays"
```

then use the **onSelect** property:

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({

onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

var start   = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

var end = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');

var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;

$('#numDays').val(days);
}
});
```

or something like simliar to that

UPDATE i have updated the jsfiddle project.. but here's the code..

(The HTML is not showing up right)
basically ensure that the input has the id='numDays'

number of days 
        <input id="numDays" readonly='true'/>

//begin JSScript:

$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: "01/07/2012", maxDate: "01/30/2012" });

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
            beforeShow: setminDate,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

            var start   = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

            var end = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');

            var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;

            $('#numDays').val(days);
            }
        });
```

Like i said, i also updated the jsfiddle.net page.. but this is what you need to do,

i just tested in FireFox, worked as expected

...gahd putting HTML in the comments was a booch... hopefully it makes sense now..

Comment: 3 answers in 10 minutes... who needs books anymore!!

Comment: Thanks. This looks fine in theory, but I can not get it to work - Can you post it to work in the JS fiddle example given? I simply want the result to be displayed in the "number of days" text box.

Comment: Thanks for your time Hanzolo! I had just figured it out and was over-complicating things. Btw. When you alter a post in JS fiddle, the url increments every time. Its a great way to show examples, but you have to remember to add a link to the updated version. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem and good to know.. jsfiddle is a pretty neat little tool

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#to').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' 
  onSelect:function(dateText,inst){
    var start   = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
    var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
    $('#resultado').val(days);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook up to the onSelect function of the datepicker.

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    beforeShow: setminDate,
    onSelect: function(date) {
     calculate(); 
    }
});
```

and move your calculate logic into a method that you can call or put it directly into the declaration.

```
function calculate() {
    var start = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    alert(days);
}
```

Comment: Is there any need to create a function to call calculate?  You could simply have onSelect: calculate without parentheses.

Comment: @Archer, if he still wants to keep the button so that it can be triggered manually then it just prevents him from having the same code twice as they can both call calculate. Other than that, no reason.